# Download file using alamofire get code -1001

Tags: ios, swift, download, alamofire

I have trouble when i download `.pdf` file from my server. I got url from server that i would download file but that url still `empty` file. When mobile hit that url, server will check that file available or not. If available it just download from my server. If not available, my server will download that file from another server until it finished and save to my server then mobile can download that file from my server.

How to wait `Alamofire` wait until my server finish download? I always get code `-1001`. This is my code

```
        let destination: DownloadRequest.DownloadFileDestination = { _, _ in
            let documentsURL:NSURL = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask).first! as NSURL
            print("***documentURL: ",documentsURL)
            let PDF_name : String = "\(id).pdf"
            let fileURL = documentsURL.appendingPathComponent(PDF_name)
            print("***fileURL: ",fileURL ?? "")
            return (fileURL!,[.removePreviousFile, .createIntermediateDirectories])
        }

        let configuration = Alamofire.SessionManager.default
        configuration.session.configuration.timeoutIntervalForRequest = 200
        configuration.session.configuration.timeoutIntervalForResource = 200

        //let destination = DownloadRequest.suggestedDownloadDestination()
        let download = Alamofire.download(url, method: .get, parameters: [:], encoding: JSONEncoding.default, headers: authHeader, to: destination).downloadProgress(closure: { (prog) in
            let json: [String: Any] = ["file": "", "progress": prog.fractionCompleted]
            observer.onNext(JSON(json))
        }).response(completionHandler: { response in
            let status = response.response?.statusCode
            if status == 200 {
                if let url = response.destinationURL {
                    let json: [String: Any] = ["file": url.path, "progress": 100]

                    observer.onNext(JSON(json))
                    observer.onCompleted()
                }
            } else {
                observer.onError(NSError(domain:"", code:500, userInfo:["error": "Error Connection".localized()]))
            }
        })
```

Thank's you all

Comment: can you try to download any file from an external(not your server) url as code looks fine?

Comment: i had try to download from another external server that file already in server and it's fine, but if that file not already in server and need to download from another server firest it's failed

Comment: so its server issue then and they should fix :)

Comment: can you help me to fix in mobile to waiting that my server download file first from another server then mobile waiting until my server finished?

Comment: you have already set timeOutInterval to 200 which looks too much. How much time server is taking to download the pdf? Also when you are getting the error response did you try the same url in any browser to check if file is placed on your server? Also try setting this in `authHeader`,  `headers["Accept"] = "application/pdf"`

Answer (score 0):

I have solve for my problem, i change `Alamofire.download` with `URLSession` with downloadTask. I dont know why, when using `Alamofire` i always get code -1001 or RTO to download file but when using `URLSession` the file can be download normally without RTO, Why? What different `Alamofire.download` with `URLSession.downloadTask?`